# Changing a variable in a thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, variables, pointers

I know this is very basic but I'm having trouble getting to it, and english is not my native language so sorry for any typos.

I have this program that must use 2 threads to calculate the sum of square roots of the first 999999 numbers. One of the threads must sum up the pairs and the other the odds. My problem comes when changing the variables of each sum in the threads, I get always 2 errors and can't even compile. I'm quite new with pointers so I'm guessing the problem is there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>


void *calc_pairs(void *sum){

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<=999999;i=i+2){

            *sum += sqrt(i);
        }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *calc_odds(void *sum1){

    int a;

    for(a=1;a<999999;a=a+2){
                *sum1 += sqrt(a);
            }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    pthread_t threads[2];

    double sum=0;
    double sum1=0;
    double sum_total;

    pthread_create(&threads[0],NULL, calc_pairs,(void *)&sum);
    pthread_create(&threads[1],NULL, calc_odds,(void *)&sum1);



    pthread_join(0);
    pthread_join(1);


    sum_total = sum1+sum;

    printf("The sum calculated on the threads is %f", sum_total);


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The errors I get are:

Invalid use of void expression. Warning: Dereferending 'void *' pointer [enabled by default]

Both errors in the lines where I calculate the squares.

Comment: You said you got an error, but it seems like a warning.? Do you get compile error or warning?

Comment: Any reason why you're not declaring the functions to take `double* sum1` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The reason is: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Comment: Good reason, I retract my comment :)

Comment: these lines: *sum1 += sqrt(a); should be: *(double*)sum1 += sqrt(a);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is you are not type casting the void* to double*. Second mistake is passing argument to pthread_join is wrong.Here is your working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>


void *calc_pairs(void *sum){

    int i;
    double *b;
    b=(double*)sum;
    for(i=0;i<=999999;i=i+2){

            *b += sqrt(i);
        }

       pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *calc_odds(void *sum1){

    int a;
    double *b;
    b=(double*)sum1;
    for(a=1;a<999999;a=a+2){
                *b += sqrt(a);
            }

        pthread_exit(NULL);

    }


    int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    pthread_t threads[2];

    double sum=0;
    double sum1=0;
    double sum_total;

    pthread_create(&threads[0],NULL, calc_pairs,(void *)&sum);
    pthread_create(&threads[1],NULL, calc_odds,(void *)&sum1);



    pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[1],NULL);


    sum_total = sum1+sum;

    printf("The sum calculated on the threads is %f", sum_total);


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped fix the program and making me understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change `*sum += sqrt(i);` to `*(double *)sum += sqrt(i);`

You can not dereference `void *`. Typecast to required type before dereferencing